# prestashop overriding and combination

Tags: overriding, prestashop, custom-fields

Hi all I have a question regarding the topic, prestashop 1.6.

I added a custom date field on the on the information page:

let's call it "customfield", and it works fine, I can fill a DATE and prestashop stores in the database.

Now I want the same field to be added in the combinations, each combination can have the same or different or null customfield value.

This is what I did regarding combination:

- created **/override/controllers/admin/templates/products/combinations.tpl** (located in the same folder there is a modified information.tpl);

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="attribute_customfield">
            {l s='Customfield'}
      </label>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input maxlength="12" type="date" id="attribute_customfield" name="attribute_customfield" value="" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

- **/override/classes/Combination.php**

```
    class Combination extends CombinationCore
    {
        public $customfield;

        /**
         * @see ObjectModel::$definition
         */
        public static $definition = array(
            'table' => 'product_attribute',
            'primary' => 'id_product_attribute',
            'fields' => array(
                'id_product' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'shop' => 'both', 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
                'location' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 64),
                'ean13' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEan13', 'size' => 13),
                'upc' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUpc', 'size' => 12),
                'quantity' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt', 'size' => 10),
                'reference' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 32),
                'supplier_reference' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 32),

                /* Shop fields */
                'wholesale_price' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isPrice', 'size' => 27),
                'price' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isNegativePrice', 'size' => 20),
                'ecotax' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isPrice', 'size' => 20),
                'weight' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isFloat'),
                'unit_price_impact' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isNegativePrice', 'size' => 20),
                'minimal_quantity' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
                'default_on' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'allow_null' => true, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
                'available_date' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isDateFormat'),

                /*added*/
                'customfield' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDateFormat'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

- **/override/classes/Product.php**

```
    class Product extends ProductCore
    {
        public $second_reference;
        public $customfield;

        public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
        {
            self::$definition['fields']['second_reference'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString');
            self::$definition['fields']['customfield'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDateFormat');
            parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop);
        }

        /**
         * @param int $quantity DEPRECATED
         * @param string $supplier_reference DEPRECATED
         */
        public function addCombinationEntity($wholesale_price, $price, $weight, $unit_impact, $ecotax, $quantity,
            $id_images, $reference, $id_supplier, $ean13, $customfield, $default, $location = null, $upc = null, $minimal_quantity = 1, array $id_shop_list = array(), $available_date = null)
        {
            $id_product_attribute = $this->addAttribute(
                $price, $weight, $unit_impact, $ecotax, $id_images,
                $reference, $ean13, $customfield, $default, $location, $upc, $minimal_quantity, $id_shop_list, $available_date);
            $this->addSupplierReference($id_supplier, $id_product_attribute);
            $result = ObjectModel::updateMultishopTable('Combination', array(
                'wholesale_price' => (float)$wholesale_price,
            ), 'a.id_product_attribute = '.(int)$id_product_attribute);

            if (!$id_product_attribute || !$result)
                return false;

                return $id_product_attribute;
        }

        /**
         * Update a product attribute
         *
         */
        public function updateAttribute($id_product_attribute, $wholesale_price, $price, $weight, $unit, $ecotax,
            $id_images, $reference, $ean13, $customfield, $default, $location = null, $upc = null, $minimal_quantity = null, $available_date = null, $update_all_fields = true, array $id_shop_list = array())
        {
            $combination = new Combination($id_product_attribute);

            if (!$update_all_fields)
                $combination->setFieldsToUpdate(array(
                    'price' => !is_null($price),
                    'wholesale_price' => !is_null($wholesale_price),
                    'ecotax' => !is_null($ecotax),
                    'weight' => !is_null($weight),
                    'unit_price_impact' => !is_null($unit),
                    'default_on' => !is_null($default),
                    'minimal_quantity' => !is_null($minimal_quantity),
                    'available_date' => !is_null($available_date),
                ));

                $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
                $weight = str_replace(',', '.', $weight);

                $combination->price = (float)$price;
                $combination->wholesale_price = (float)$wholesale_price;
                $combination->ecotax = (float)$ecotax;
                $combination->weight = (float)$weight;
                $combination->unit_price_impact = (float)$unit;
                $combination->reference = pSQL($reference);
                $combination->location = pSQL($location);
                $combination->ean13 = pSQL($ean13);
                $combination->customfield = pSQL($customfield);
                $combination->upc = pSQL($upc);
                $combination->default_on = (int)$default;
                $combination->minimal_quantity = (int)$minimal_quantity;
                $combination->available_date = $available_date ? pSQL($available_date) : '0000-00-00';

                if (count($id_shop_list))
                    $combination->id_shop_list = $id_shop_list;

                    $combination->save();

                    if (is_array($id_images) && count($id_images))
                        $combination->setImages($id_images);

                        $id_default_attribute = (int)Product::updateDefaultAttribute($this->id);
                        if ($id_default_attribute)
                            $this->cache_default_attribute = $id_default_attribute;

                            // Sync stock Reference, EAN13 and UPC for this attribute
                            if (Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT') && StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($this->id, Context::getContext()->shop->id))
                                Db::getInstance()->update('stock', array(
                                    'reference' => pSQL($reference),
                                    'ean13'     => pSQL($ean13),
                                    'customfield'  => pSQL($customfield),
                                    'upc'        => pSQL($upc),
                                ), 'id_product = '.$this->id.' AND id_product_attribute = '.(int)$id_product_attribute);

                                Hook::exec('actionProductAttributeUpdate', array('id_product_attribute' => (int)$id_product_attribute));
                                Tools::clearColorListCache($this->id);

                                return true;
        }

        /**
         * Add a product attribute
         * @since 1.5.0.1
         *
         * @param float $price Additional price
         * @param float $weight Additional weight
         * @param float $ecotax Additional ecotax
         * @param int $id_images Image ids
         * @param string $reference Reference
         * @param string $location Location
         * @param string $ean13 Ean-13 barcode
         * @param bool $default Is default attribute for product
         * @param int $minimal_quantity Minimal quantity to add to cart
         * @return mixed $id_product_attribute or false
         */
        public function addAttribute($price, $weight, $unit_impact, $ecotax, $id_images, $reference, $ean13, $customfield,
            $default, $location = null, $upc = null, $minimal_quantity = 1, array $id_shop_list = array(), $available_date = null)
        {
            if (!$this->id)
                return;

                $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
                $weight = str_replace(',', '.', $weight);

                $combination = new Combination();
                $combination->id_product = (int)$this->id;
                $combination->price = (float)$price;
                $combination->ecotax = (float)$ecotax;
                $combination->quantity = 0;
                $combination->weight = (float)$weight;
                $combination->unit_price_impact = (float)$unit_impact;
                $combination->reference = pSQL($reference);
                $combination->location = pSQL($location);
                $combination->ean13 = pSQL($ean13);
                $combination->customfield = pSQL($customfield);
                $combination->upc = pSQL($upc);
                $combination->default_on = (int)$default;
                $combination->minimal_quantity = (int)$minimal_quantity;
                $combination->available_date = $available_date;

                if (count($id_shop_list))
                    $combination->id_shop_list = array_unique($id_shop_list);

                    $combination->add();

                    if (!$combination->id)
                        return false;

                        $total_quantity = (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
            SELECT SUM(quantity) as quantity
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available
            WHERE id_product = '.(int)$this->id.'
            AND id_product_attribute <> 0 '
                            );

                        if (!$total_quantity)
                            Db::getInstance()->update('stock_available', array('quantity' => 0), '`id_product` = '.$this->id);

                            $id_default_attribute = Product::updateDefaultAttribute($this->id);

                            if ($id_default_attribute)
                            {
                                $this->cache_default_attribute = $id_default_attribute;
                                if (!$combination->available_date)
                                    $this->setAvailableDate();
                            }

                            if (!empty($id_images))
                                $combination->setImages($id_images);

                                Tools::clearColorListCache($this->id);

                                if (Configuration::get('PS_DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE_NEW_PRODUCT') != 0 && Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT'))
                                {
                                    $warehouse_location_entity = new WarehouseProductLocation();
                                    $warehouse_location_entity->id_product = $this->id;
                                    $warehouse_location_entity->id_product_attribute = (int)$combination->id;
                                    $warehouse_location_entity->id_warehouse = Configuration::get('PS_DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE_NEW_PRODUCT');
                                    $warehouse_location_entity->location = pSQL('');
                                    $warehouse_location_entity->save();
                                }

                                return (int)$combination->id;
        }

        /**
         * Get all available attribute groups
         *
         * @param int $id_lang Language id
         * @return array Attribute groups
         */
        public function getAttributesGroups($id_lang)
        {
            if (!Combination::isFeatureActive())
                return array();
                $sql = 'SELECT ag.`id_attribute_group`, ag.`is_color_group`, agl.`name` AS group_name, agl.`public_name` AS public_group_name,
                    a.`id_attribute`, al.`name` AS attribute_name, a.`color` AS attribute_color, product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute`,
                    IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, product_attribute_shop.`price`, product_attribute_shop.`ecotax`, product_attribute_shop.`weight`,
                    product_attribute_shop.`default_on`, pa.`reference`, pa.`customfield`, product_attribute_shop.`unit_price_impact`,
                    product_attribute_shop.`minimal_quantity`, product_attribute_shop.`available_date`, ag.`group_type`
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('pa', 'pa').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_combination` pac ON (pac.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute` a ON (a.`id_attribute` = pac.`id_attribute`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_group` ag ON (ag.`id_attribute_group` = a.`id_attribute_group`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_lang` al ON (a.`id_attribute` = al.`id_attribute`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_group_lang` agl ON (ag.`id_attribute_group` = agl.`id_attribute_group`)
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('attribute', 'a').'
                WHERE pa.`id_product` = '.(int)$this->id.'
                    AND al.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.'
                    AND agl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.'
                GROUP BY id_attribute_group, id_product_attribute
                ORDER BY ag.`position` ASC, a.`position` ASC, agl.`name` ASC';
                return Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
        }

        /**
         * Get product attribute combination by id_product_attribute
         * @return array Product attribute combination by id_product_attribute
         */
        public function getAttributeCombinationsById($id_product_attribute, $id_lang)
        {
            if (!Combination::isFeatureActive())
                return array();
                $sql = 'SELECT pa.*, product_attribute_shop.*, ag.`id_attribute_group`, ag.`is_color_group`, agl.`name` AS group_name, al.`name` AS attribute_name,
                    a.`id_attribute`
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_combination` pac ON pac.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute` a ON a.`id_attribute` = pac.`id_attribute`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_group` ag ON ag.`id_attribute_group` = a.`id_attribute_group`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_lang` al ON (a.`id_attribute` = al.`id_attribute` AND al.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'attribute_group_lang` agl ON (ag.`id_attribute_group` = agl.`id_attribute_group` AND agl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                WHERE pa.`id_product` = '.(int)$this->id.'
                AND pa.`id_product_attribute` = '.(int)$id_product_attribute.'
                GROUP BY pa.`id_product_attribute`, ag.`id_attribute_group`
                ORDER BY pa.`id_product_attribute`';

                $res = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);

                //Get quantity of each variations
                foreach ($res as $key => $row)
                {
                    $cache_key = $row['id_product'].'_'.$row['id_product_attribute'].'_quantity';

                    if (!Cache::isStored($cache_key))
                    {
                        $result = StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct($row['id_product'], $row['id_product_attribute']);
                        Cache::store(
                            $cache_key,
                            $result
                            );
                        $res[$key]['quantity'] = $result;
                    }
                    else
                        $res[$key]['quantity'] = Cache::retrieve($cache_key);
                }

                return $res;
        }
    }
```

- **/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php**

```
    class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore
    {
        /**
         * Assign template vars related to attribute groups and colors
         */
        protected function assignAttributesGroups()
        {
            $colors = array();
            $groups = array();

            // @todo (RM) should only get groups and not all declination ?
            $attributes_groups = $this->product->getAttributesGroups($this->context->language->id);
            if (is_array($attributes_groups) && $attributes_groups)
            {
                $combination_images = $this->product->getCombinationImages($this->context->language->id);
                $combination_prices_set = array();
                foreach ($attributes_groups as $k => $row)
                {
                    // Color management
                    if (isset($row['is_color_group']) && $row['is_color_group'] && (isset($row['attribute_color']) && $row['attribute_color']) || (file_exists(_PS_COL_IMG_DIR_.$row['id_attribute'].'.jpg')))
                    {
                        $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['value'] = $row['attribute_color'];
                        $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['name'] = $row['attribute_name'];
                        if (!isset($colors[$row['id_attribute']]['attributes_quantity']))
                            $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['attributes_quantity'] = 0;
                            $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['attributes_quantity'] += (int)$row['quantity'];
                    }

   ...

        }

    }
```

- **/override/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php**

```
<?php
class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore
{
   public function processProductAttribute()
   {
       // Don't process if the combination fields have not been submitted
       if (!Combination::isFeatureActive() || !Tools::getValue('attribute_combination_list'))
           return;

       if (Validate::isLoadedObject($product = $this->object))
       {
           if ($this->isProductFieldUpdated('attribute_price') && (!Tools::getIsset('attribute_price') || Tools::getIsset('attribute_price') == null))
               $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The price attribute is required.');
           if (!Tools::getIsset('attribute_combination_list') || Tools::isEmpty(Tools::getValue('attribute_combination_list')))
               $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must add at least one attribute.');

           $array_checks = array(
               'reference' => 'isReference',
               'supplier_reference' => 'isReference',
               'location' => 'isReference',
               'ean13' => 'isEan13',
               'upc' => 'isUpc',
               'wholesale_price' => 'isPrice',
               'price' => 'isPrice', 
               'ecotax' => 'isPrice',
               'quantity' => 'isInt',
               'weight' => 'isUnsignedFloat',
               'unit_price_impact' => 'isPrice',
               'default_on' => 'isBool',
               'minimal_quantity' => 'isUnsignedInt',
               'available_date' => 'isDateFormat'
           );
           foreach ($array_checks as $property => $check)
               if (Tools::getValue('attribute_'.$property) !== false && !call_user_func(array('Validate', $check), Tools::getValue('attribute_'.$property)))

...
                               $this->isProductFieldUpdated('attribute_ecotax') ? Tools::getValue('attribute_ecotax') : null,
                               Tools::getValue('id_image_attr'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_reference'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_ean13'),
                               Tools::getValue('customfield'),
                               $this->isProductFieldUpdated('attribute_default') ?  Tools::getValue('attribute_default') : null,
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_location'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_upc'),
                               $this->isProductFieldUpdated('attribute_minimal_quantity') ? Tools::getValue('attribute_minimal_quantity') : null,
                               $this->isProductFieldUpdated('available_date_attribute') ? Tools::getValue('available_date_attribute') : null, false);
                               StockAvailable::setProductDependsOnStock((int)$product->id, $product->depends_on_stock, null, (int)$id_product_attribute);
                               StockAvailable::setProductOutOfStock((int)$product->id, $product->out_of_stock, null, (int)$id_product_attribute);
                       }
                   }
                   else
                       $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have permission to add this.');
               }
               // Add new
               else
               {
                   if ($this->tabAccess['add'] === '1')
                   {
                       if ($product->productAttributeExists(Tools::getValue('attribute_combination_list')))
                           $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This combination already exists.');
                       else
                       {
                           $id_product_attribute = $product->addCombinationEntity(
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_wholesale_price'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_price') *  Tools::getValue('attribute_price_impact'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_weight') * Tools::getValue('attribute_weight_impact'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_unity') * Tools::getValue('attribute_unit_impact'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_ecotax'),
                               0,
                               Tools::getValue('id_image_attr'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_reference'),
                               null,
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_ean13'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_default'),
                               Tools::getValue('attribute_location'),
                               Tools::getValue('customfield'),

...

           }
       }
   }

   /**
    * @param Product $product
    * @throws Exception
    * @throws SmartyException
    */
   public function initFormInformations($product)
   {
       if (!$this->default_form_language)
           $this->getLanguages();

       $data = $this->createTemplate($this->tpl_form);

       $currency = $this->context->currency;

       $data->assign(array(
           'languages' => $this->_languages,
           'default_form_language' => $this->default_form_language,
           'currency' => $currency
       ));
       $this->object = $product;
       //$this->display = 'edit';
       $data->assign('product_name_redirected', Product::getProductName((int)$product->id_product_redirected, null, (int)$this->context->language->id));
       /*
       * Form for adding a virtual product like software, mp3, etc...
       */
       $product_download = new ProductDownload();
       if ($id_product_download = $product_download->getIdFromIdProduct($this->getFieldValue($product, 'id')))
           $product_download = new ProductDownload($id_product_download);

       $product->{'productDownload'} = $product_download;

       $product_props = array();
       // global informations
       array_push($product_props, 'reference', 'ean13', 'customfield', 'upc',
       'available_for_order', 'show_price', 'online_only',
       'id_manufacturer'
       );

       // specific / detailled information
       array_push($product_props,
       // physical product
       'width', 'height', 'weight', 'active',
       // virtual product
       'is_virtual', 'cache_default_attribute',
       // customization
       'uploadable_files', 'text_fields'
       );
       // prices
       array_push($product_props,
           'price', 'wholesale_price', 'id_tax_rules_group', 'unit_price_ratio', 'on_sale',
           'unity', 'minimum_quantity', 'additional_shipping_cost',
           'available_now', 'available_later', 'available_date'
       );

...
   }


   /**
    * @param Product $product
    * @param Currency|array|int $currency
    * @return string
    */
   public function renderListAttributes($product, $currency)
   {
       $this->bulk_actions = array('delete' => array('text' => $this->l('Delete selected'), 'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')));
       $this->addRowAction('edit');
       $this->addRowAction('default');
       $this->addRowAction('delete');

       $default_class = 'highlighted';

       $this->fields_list = array(
           'attributes' => array('title' => $this->l('Attribute - value pair'), 'align' => 'left'),
           'price' => array('title' => $this->l('Impact on price'), 'type' => 'price', 'align' => 'left'),
           'weight' => array('title' => $this->l('Impact on weight'), 'align' => 'left'),
           'reference' => array('title' => $this->l('Reference'), 'align' => 'left'),
           'ean13' => array('title' => $this->l('EAN-13'), 'align' => 'left'),
           'upc' => array('title' => $this->l('UPC'), 'align' => 'left')
       );

       if ($product->id)
       {
           /* Build attributes combinations */
           $combinations = $product->getAttributeCombinations($this->context->language->id);
           $groups = array();
           $comb_array = array();
           if (is_array($combinations))
           {
               $combination_images = $product->getCombinationImages($this->context->language->id);
               foreach ($combinations as $k => $combination)
               {
                   $price_to_convert = Tools::convertPrice($combination['price'], $currency);
                   $price = Tools::displayPrice($price_to_convert, $currency);

                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['id_product_attribute'] = $combination['id_product_attribute'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['attributes'][] = array($combination['group_name'], $combination['attribute_name'], $combination['id_attribute']);
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['wholesale_price'] = $combination['wholesale_price'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['price'] = $price;
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['weight'] = $combination['weight'].Configuration::get('PS_WEIGHT_UNIT');
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['unit_impact'] = $combination['unit_price_impact'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['reference'] = $combination['reference'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['ean13'] = $combination['ean13'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['customfield'] = $combination['customfield'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]['upc'] = $combination['upc'];
                   $comb_array[$combination['id_product_attribute']]
...
   }

}
```

- **/js/admin/product.js**

```
        function editProductAttribute (url, parent){
            $.ajax({...
                success: function(data) {
                    // color the selected line
                    parent.siblings().removeClass('selected-line');
                    parent.addClass('selected-line');

                    $('#add_new_combination').show();
                    $('#attribute_quantity').show();
                    $('#product_att_list').html('');
                    self.removeButtonCombination('update');
                    scroll_if_anchor('#add_new_combination');
                    var wholesale_price = Math.abs(data[0]['wholesale_price']);
                    var price = data[0]['price'];
                    var weight = data[0]['weight'];
                    var unit_impact = data[0]['unit_price_impact'];
                    var reference = data[0]['reference'];
                    var ean = data[0]['ean13'];
                    //MIO
                    var customfield = data[0]['customfield'];
                    .....
                    .....

                    self.fillCombination(
                        wholesale_price,
                        price, 
                        weight,
                        unit_impact,
                        reference,
                        ean,
                        customfield,
                        ...
                    );

/**AND LATER**/

    this.fillCombination = function(wholesale_price, price_impact, weight_impact, unit_impact, reference,
    ean, customfield, quantity, image, old_attr, id_product_attribute, default_attribute, eco_tax, upc, minimal_quantity, available_date)
    {
        var link = '';
        self.init_elems();
        $('#stock_mvt_attribute').show();
        $('#initial_stock_attribute').hide();
        ...     
        getE('attribute_customfield').value = customfield;
```

These are all the files i overrided and modified

Of course it doesn't work, it doesn't save info into the db correctly, sometimes if the one in information is set the it copies that one instead.

What I did wrong? And what should I do instead

Comment: I will edit with more complete code